# How to init slug mongoid_slug for generated model in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a project and everything is near complete! I've just used mongoid_slug for my project to make readable link! In my model, i have 2 more lines: "include Mongoid:slug" and "slug :title" and in my controller I call *.find_by_slug(params[:id]) but the result is always is null! After finding for a while, I find out that my old models does't load the slug!! I know that I have to init my slug for my model first, and I have to write a rake tastk in db.rb! However, I dont' know how to write it!! Is there any suggestion? Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using inherited resources? if so yo will need to override the definitions of collection and resource to use find by slug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i found my own answer! The only thing i have to do is to initialize a rake task to add the slug to all my old model! Then i could use the slug easily! :D! Anyway, thank you very much!